# Using For-Loop to make hidden table rows appear when populated

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to pass data from one table to be used in another on the same page in javascript.  The second table has rows 2-n hidden and I'd like them to dynamically appear when they're populated with data from the first table.

The first table that can be filled out looks like this:

```
<h3><em>Per Serving</em></h3>

<form name="ingredient-table">
<datalist id="ingredients">
<option value="Creatine Monohydrate">
<option value="St. John's Wort">
<option value="5-HTP">
<option value="Magnesium">
<option value="Magnesium Citrate">
<option value="Vitamin A">
<option value="Vitamin D3">
<option value="Cocoa">
<option value="Stevia">
<option value="Lavender Root Extract">
</datalist>
<table border="1" style="padding: 5px;">
<tr>
    <td>Ingredient Name</td>
    <td>Amount (in Mg)</td>
    <td>% Carrier</td>
    <td>$$/Kilo</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Total Carrier Volume</td>
    <td>Total Ingredient Volume</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="a" list="ingredients"></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="b"> Mg</input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="c"></input> %</td>
    <td><input id="d"></input></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="calculate('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')">Calculate Final 
Volume</button></td>
    <td id="e"><input></input></td>
    <td id="f"><input></input></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row2')">New Ingredient</a></td>

</tr>
<tr id="row2" style="display: none;">
    <td><input type="text" id="h" list="ingredients"></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="i"> Mg</input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="j"></input> %</td>
    <td><input id="k"></input></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="calculate('h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm')">Calculate Final 
Volume</button></td>
    <td id="l"><input></input></td>
    <td id="m"><input></input></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row3')">New Ingredient</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row2')">Delete Ingredient</a></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row3" style="display: none;">
    <td><input type="text" id="o" list="ingredients"></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="p"> Mg</input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="q"></input> %</td>
    <td><input id="r"></input></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="calculate('o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't')">Calculate Final 
Volume</button></td>
    <td id="s"><input></input></td>
    <td id="t"><input></input></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row4')">New Ingredient</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row3')">Delete Ingredient</a></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row4" style="display: none;">
    <td><input type="text" id="v" list="ingredients"></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="w"> Mg</input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="x"></input> %</td>
    <td><input id="y"></input></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="calculate('v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a1')">Calculate Final 
Volume</button></td>
    <td id="z"><input></input></td>
    <td id="a1"><input></input></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row5')">New Ingredient</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row4')">Delete Ingredient</a></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row5" style="display: none;">
    <td><input type="text" id="a3" list="ingredients"></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="a4"> Mg</input></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="a5"></input> %</td>
    <td><input id="a6"></input></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="calculate('a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8')">Calculate   
Final Volume</button></td>
    <td id="a7"><input></input></td>
    <td id="a8"><input></input></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="noMoreRows()">New Ingredient</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggleRow('row5')">Delete Ingredient</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The second table that accepts the data from the above table is this:

```
<h3>Per Bottle</h3>
<button type="button" onclick="bottle_volume('td1', 'td2', 'td3', 'td4', 'td5', 'td6', 'td7',  
'td8','td9', 'td10', 'td11', 'td12', 'td13', 'td14', 'td15', 'td16', 'td17', 'td18', 'td19', 
'td20')">Click to Calculate Bottle Totals</button>
<table border="1" style="padding: 5px;">
<tr>
<td>Ingredient</td>
<td>Total Amount of Carrier</td>
<td>Total Per Bottle</td>
<td>Total Cost Per Bottle</td>
</tr>
<tr id="outputRow1">
<td id="td1"><input></input></td>
<td id="td2"><input></input></td>
<td id="td3"><input></input></td>
<td id="td4"><input></input></td>
</tr>
<tr id="outputRow2" style="display: none;">
<td id="td5"><input></input></td>
<td id="td6"><input></input></td>
<td id="td7"><input></input></td>
<td id="td8"><input></input></td>
</tr>
<tr id="outputRow3" style="display: none;">
<td id="td9"><input></input></td>
<td id="td10"><input></input></td>
<td id="td11"><input></input></td>
<td id="td12"><input></input></td>
</tr>
<tr id="outputRow4" style="display: none;">
<td id="td13"><input></input></td>
<td id="td14"><input></input></td>
<td id="td15"><input></input></td>
<td id="td16"><input></input></td>
</tr>
<tr id="outputRow5" style="display: none;">
<td id="td17"><input></input></td>
<td id="td18"><input></input></td>
<td id="td19"><input></input></td>
<td id="td20"><input></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="td21"><strong>Totals</strong></td>
<td id="td22"></td>
<td id="td23"></td>
<td id="td24"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The for-loop I use on the second table to make the rows appear is this:

```
    var rowArray = ["outputRow1", "outputRow2", "outputRow3", "outputRow4", "outputRow5"];      
    for (i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).innerHTML !== "") {
            document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).style.display = 'table row';
        }

        else {
        document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

This doesn't cause the hidden rows to appear when they're populated.  It doesn't seem to have any effect at all, and also does not cause any errors to appear in the javascript console.

The *entire* function that happens when you hit the button "Click to Calculate Bottle Totals" 
is bottle_volume('td1', 'td2',...) and it looks like this:

```
var bottle_volume = function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11,   
arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15, arg16, arg17, arg18, arg19, arg20) {
    var ing1Value = calculate('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
    var ing1 = ing1Value[0];
    var ing1_carrier = ing1Value[3]*30;
    var ing1_volume = ing1Value[4]*30;
    var ing1_cost = (ing1_volume/1000000)*ing1Value[2];
    var name1 = document.getElementById(arg1).innerHTML = ing1;
    var carrier1 = document.getElementById(arg2).innerHTML = ing1_carrier.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ing_volume1 = document.getElementById(arg3).innerHTML = ing1_volume.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ingCost1 = document.getElementById(arg4).innerHTML ="$" + ing1_cost.toFixed(2)*1;

    var ing2Value = calculate('h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm');
    var ing2 = ing2Value[0];
    var ing2_carrier = ing2Value[3]*30;
    var ing2_volume = ing2Value[4]*30;
    var ing2_cost = (ing2_volume/1000000)*ing2Value[2];
    var name2 = document.getElementById(arg5).innerHTML = ing2;
    var carrier2 = document.getElementById(arg6).innerHTML = ing2_carrier.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ing_volume2 = document.getElementById(arg7).innerHTML = ing2_volume.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ingCost2 = document.getElementById(arg8).innerHTML = "$" + ing2_cost.toFixed(2)*1;

    var ing3Value = calculate('o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't');
    var ing3 = ing3Value[0];
    var ing3_carrier = ing3Value[3]*30;
    var ing3_volume = ing3Value[4]*30;
    var ing3_cost = (ing3_volume/1000000)*ing3Value[2];
    var name3 = document.getElementById(arg9).innerHTML = ing3;
    var carrier3 = document.getElementById(arg10).innerHTML = ing3_carrier.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ing_volume3 = document.getElementById(arg11).innerHTML = ing3_volume.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ingCost3 = document.getElementById(arg12).innerHTML = "$" + ing3_cost.toFixed(2)*1;

    var ing4Value = calculate('v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a1');
    var ing4 = ing4Value[0];
    var ing4_carrier = ing4Value[3]*30;
    var ing4_volume = ing4Value[4]*30;
    var ing4_cost = (ing4_volume/1000000)*ing4Value[2];
    var name4 = document.getElementById(arg13).innerHTML = ing4;
    var carrier4 = document.getElementById(arg14).innerHTML = ing4_carrier.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ing_volume4 = document.getElementById(arg15).innerHTML = ing4_volume.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ingCost4 = document.getElementById(arg16).innerHTML = "$" + ing4_cost.toFixed(2)*1;

    var ing5Value = calculate('a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8');
    var ing5 = ing5Value[0];
    var ing5_carrier = ing5Value[3]*30;
    var ing5_volume = ing5Value[4]*30;
    var ing5_cost = (ing5_volume/1000000)*ing5Value[2];
    var name5 = document.getElementById(arg17).innerHTML = ing5;
    var carrier5 = document.getElementById(arg18).innerHTML = ing5_carrier.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ing_volume5 = document.getElementById(arg19).innerHTML = ing5_volume.toFixed(2)*1;
    var ingCost5 = document.getElementById(arg20).innerHTML = "$" + ing5_cost.toFixed(2)*1;

    carrierPerBottle = ing1_carrier + ing2_carrier + ing3_carrier + ing4_carrier + ing5_carrier;
    volumePerBottle = ing1_volume + ing2_volume + ing3_volume + ing4_volume + ing5_volume;
    costPerBottle = ing1_cost + ing2_cost + ing3_cost + ing4_cost + ing5_cost;

    document.getElementById("td22").innerHTML = carrierPerBottle.toFixed(2)*1;
    document.getElementById("td23").innerHTML = volumePerBottle.toFixed(2)*1;
    document.getElementById("td24").innerHTML = "$" + costPerBottle.toFixed(2)*1;

    var rowArray = ["outputRow1", "outputRow2", "outputRow3", "outputRow4", "outputRow5"];

    for (i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).innerHTML !== "") {
            document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).style.display = 'table row';
        }

        else {
        document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
};
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my for-loop.  I'm only using javascript for this and would prefer not to use jquery.

You can see the whole page here: [Supplement Pricer](http://www.healthkismet.com/supplement_pricer.html)

Comment: I have my doubts about the effectiveness of "hiding" rows instead of "deleting" them when you press "Delete Ingredient."

Comment: your code could be at least 1/3rd the size that it is now with jquery and loops, just as an fyi

Comment: @indubitablee - I have no doubt that you're right, unfortunately I'm trying to sink my teeth into javascript right now, and this questions marks my first time using for-loops for a program in any context, hence my difficulty with them.

Comment: You've got the right idea of for-loops, it works fine. JQuery would help a lot to simplify things (once you understand jQuery syntax) but the biggest issue comes from hard-coding things. This example could really benefit from a dynamic approach; writing a foreach loop for each (haha) row and generating that instead of writing 5+ rows for everything. Imagine the nightmare that would come from having 100+ ingredients!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rendered HTML for `outputRow1`:

```
<tr id="outputRow1">
    <td id="td1"><input></input></td>
    <td id="td2"><input></input></td>
    <td id="td3"><input></input></td>
    <td id="td4"><input></input></td>
</tr>
```

Same goes for `outputRow2, outputRow3, outputRow4 and outputRow5`, but they have different elements in their `<td>`.

When you call this function in Javascript:

```
var rowArray = ["outputRow1", "outputRow2", "outputRow3", "outputRow4", "outputRow5"];
for (i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).innerHTML !== "") {
...
```

You're checking to see if `outputRow1` has anything in it's Inner HTML, which it does. Therefore, it's going to display the row **no matter what.**

Basically, you need to check if their corresponding rows are set to `display:none` or `display:table-row` and display the `outputRowN` accordingly. I think this will work, but give it a try:

```
var rowArray = ["row2", "row3", "row4", "row5"]; // Skip row 1, always shows;
var outputArray = ["outputRow2", "outputRow3", "outputRow4", "outputRow5"];
for (i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
  if (document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).getAttribute("style") != "display: none;"){
    console.log("True");
    document.getElementById(outputArray[i]).setAttribute("style", "");
  } else {
    console.log("False");
    document.getElementById(outputArray[i]).setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
  }
}
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Working Fiddle Example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e223a9qt/)

Comment: I tried this and got a similar result to the issues experienced with the answer provided by indubitabilee - they all show automatically. I DO understand what you're saying now, and realize the issue with my IF statement, and making sure it can return true/false under the appropriate circumstances, and the gist of your code, so I will fiddle with this.

Comment: I figured it out, making an edit. Check it out now. I was missing the `display: none;` `;` in the if check, but it should work as intended now. I wish I could hook you up to my `localhost` to show you, but if you replace from `rowArray` you should be able to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).innerHTML !== "") {
    document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).style.display = 'table row';
}
```

try changing the above code to (take out 'table row'):

```
if (document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).innerHTML !== "") {
    document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).style.display = '';
}
```

i dont know if this will work, but its easier to post code in code format in the answer box then make a comment for it.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I just tried it and it causes all the rows in the second table to reappear, not just the ones that have been populated.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel then thats a problem with the condition of the if statement, because all the rows are satisfying the condition of the if statement and executing ...display=""; when only the populated ones should be.  do a console.log(document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).innerHTML !== "") inside the loop (but outside the if) and post what you see from the console please

Comment: The if check if the output row is `""` before it fills it, so it's always going to return true and display the rows. You need to fill them first, then display them. (Hope that makes sense)

Comment: @indubitablee it returns 'true'.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel OHHH i see what you're saying now, hahaha then that if statement is kinda useless if it's always true. we need to change that if statement to say something along the lines of if(elementFromTable1.innherHTML !== "") {//then my code to show the corresponding row in table 2}. so which element in table one needs to be filled out to trigger a table 2 row to show?

Comment: @TimLewis - I'm terribly sorry, but that honestly doesn't make sense.  I think you're referring to the comment made by indubitablee - because my console.log check returned true.  Does this mean I should change the position of my for-loop within the function?  EDIT - rather, I should change my IF statement because it doesn't distinguish whether or not the table is filled, thus making it useless.

Comment: oh wow, hahaha tim's comment confused me i thought jonathan wrote it....wow @JonathanBechtel ignore my previous comment about your if statement being useless, i misread the author of the comment. let me reread lol

Comment: @JonathanBechtel Sorry... Let me word this correctly first. Gimme a minute to make an answer.

Comment: @indubitablee - in table one, once you hit 'calculate final volume' it triggers a function called calculate(), which then returns values that can be fed into bottle_volume(), which is the function that's called when you hit the button "Click to Calculate Bottle Totals" and contains the for-loop.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel understood, but what actual element in table 1 needs be filled out (have contents) in order that table 2 row shows?

Comment: @indubitablee - it'll actually zero fill if you leave everything blank, so I'm not sure if you technically need any of them.  If you leave everything blank and then call bottle_volume() the whole table populates with 0's.

Answer (score 0):

so i came up with another answer that requires at least one of the inputs of a row from table 1 to be filled out in order for the corresponding row in table 2 to be shown. i require one input to have at least some contents because if its based on if the row from table 1 is showing, you would just have a bunch of 0's in a bunch of rows in table 2.

heres the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/50/

```
<a href="#" class="show" onclick="populate()">calculate</a><br/><br/>

table 1<br/>
<table border="1" style="padding: 5px;">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td id="td1"><input></input></td>
        <td id="td2"><input></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td id="td3"><input></input></td>
        <td id="td4"><input></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
        <td id="td5"><input></input></td>
        <td id="td6"><input></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
table 2<br/>
<table border="1" style="padding: 5px;" class="table2">
    <tr id="outputRow1">
        <td><input value="row1"></input></td>
        <td><input></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="outputRow2" style="display:none;">
        <td><input value="row2"></input></td>
        <td><input></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="outputRow3" style="display:none;">
        <td><input value="row3"></input></td>
        <td><input></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>

function populate() {
    var rowArray = ["row2", "row3"]; 
    var outArray = ["outputRow2", "outputRow3"];      
    for (i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
        var inputs = document.getElementById(rowArray[i]).getElementsByTagName('input'); // get the inputs of table 1 row
        var show = false;
        for (j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
            if (inputs[j].value.length > 0) { // if at least one text box has contents, show = true
                show = true;
            }
        }
        if (show == true) {
            document.getElementById(outArray[i]).style.display = "table-row";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(outArray[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

when the information from the text boxes of a given row are all empty in table 1, the row in table 2 will hide.  hope this is suitable for your needs.